# How to sql query to laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

My SQL QUERY :

```
DB::raw("SELECT serviceProvider.*, serviceProviderItem.data as price FROM serviceProvider, serviceProviderItem WHERE serviceProvider.id in(34,35) and (serviceProviderItem.providerid = serviceProvider.id) and (serviceProviderItem.itemid = '164')");
```

to Laravel query ?

fixed code :

```
DB::table("serviceProvider")->
join('serviceProviderItem', 'serviceProviderItem.providerid', '=', 'serviceProvider.id')
->select("serviceProviderItem.data")
->select("serviceProvider.*")
->where('serviceProviderItem.itemid', $priceVariable)
->whereIn('serviceProvider.id', $providerIdler)
->orderby("data", "asc")
->paginate(15);
```

Comment: when you say "Laravel query" you want to use Eloquent or the query builder?

Comment: yes example : ServiceProvider::where(eg...)

Comment: Did you create the relationship on your models? (ServiceProvider and ServiceProviderItem) if so can you post it here so then we can figure it out how to build the query using Eloquent

Comment: sql query true. Only query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass you `DB::raw` query into `DB::select` in order to execute raw queries in Laravel.

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT serviceProvider.*, serviceProviderItem.data as price FROM serviceProvider, serviceProviderItem WHERE serviceProvider.id in(34,35) and (serviceProviderItem.providerid = serviceProvider.id) and (serviceProviderItem.itemid = '164')"));
```

And I also suggest you to use Eloquent of Laravel this will make you code more neat and readable.

Comment: return Call to a member function get() on array.
I don't know how to create with Laravel

Comment: Just keep DB::select and remove get() method and than check

Comment: For more reference you can check this document of Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries

Comment: @nonenone reason for this call to undefined method was because the query was already executed with select method and given a set of array in return and then also we were trying to use get method on it which is generally used to retrieve the set of records from queries.